# Mixing JPA with reactive code in Spring MVC app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

I have a Spring MVC (not WebFlux) app that makes use of the `WebClient` class from the WebFlux project. Except for the `WebClient`-related code, all existing code in the app is async based on `CompletableFuture`s, and blocking calls to JPA are usually done like this:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
  private final MyRepository repo;
  private final Executor executor;  // configured by me & injected by Spring

  ...

  @Async
  public CompletableFuture<MyResult> doSomething() {
    return CompletableFuture
        .supplyAsync(() => repo.findById(...), executor)
        .thenApply(...);
  }
}
```

However, with `WebClient` I'm no longer sure how to make calls to JPA based on the results returned by `WebClient`. For example:

```
public Mono<Foo> fetchFooUsingWebClient() { ... }

public void saveFooBlocking(Foo foo) { /* uses JPA */ }

// Option 1
fetchFooUsingWebClient()
    .flatMap(foo -> {
      var cf = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() => saveFooBlocking(foo), executor);
      return Mono.fromFuture(cf);
    });

// Option 2
fetchFooUsingWebClient()
    .flatMap(foo -> Mono.fromRunnable(() => saveFooBlocking(foo)));
```

I understand that 1 is eager while 2 is reactive, but what I don't understand are:

- `Mono.fromRunnable` doesn't take an executor. Does it run the `Runnable` on its own scheduler thread?
- I heard that using the reactive `WebClient` in a Spring MVC app is also supposed to bring performance benefits. But in my case where I'm already using my own executor throughout the MVC app, is it bad to use `Mono.fromRunnable` instead of my own executor?

(I found the [relevant Spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-concurrency-model) that describes how to make blocking calls using `publishOn`, but I think that's for the scenario where I have a reactive WebFlux app. In the case of a MVC app, I can't find any relevant docs.)

Comment: if you use `block` in a non reactive application, webclient will act exactly like `RestTemplate`

Comment: @ThomasAndolf not true actually. 1), depends on the http client its using, it could be quite different, thinking about thread pool, IO model. 2) the APIs are quite different, so your programming way is also quite different.

Answer (score -1):

`WebClient` has very limited worker threads, you should not do blocking operations on those threads (option 2), and I assume you don't want to go with option 1 which is not easy to read and not very necessary. In your case, you could do

```
fetchFooUsingWebClient()
.publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
.map(foo -> saveFooBlocking(foo))
//.bla - other operators, eg. doOnNext, doOnError, etc
.subscribe() // or .block() if you want to get the result, note, this will blcok the caller thread (which calls fetchFooUsingWebClient)
```

Comment: I'm actually fine with option 1, as long as it's efficient. I feel it's the best if I can have a central `TaskScheduler` for the MVC app that runs everything, instead of bringing in a reactive `Scheduler` unnecessarily. Despite it being ugly, do you know if option 1 is efficient?

Comment: I'd suggest you to use the reactor constructs if possible given you are already using it. There is one thing you need to pay attention is `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` uses commons pool which by default only has very few threads. Might not be a good idea to use it as it might be a bottleneck (db calls waiting thread to be executed). 

And bringing a custom `TaskManager` seems like an overkill to me, and using it right is also not that easy. I would suggest rely on the abstractions you are already using instead of creating your own unless necessary.

Comment: `TaskManager` was a typo, I meant the Spring `TaskExecutor`. I have a thread pool task executor configured for my Spring MVC app, and I run all the `CompletableFuture`s on that specific thread pool task executor by `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(..., executor)`.

Comment: "I'd suggest you to use the reactor constructs if possible given you are already using it." My main concern is exactly because the rest of the MVC app is NOT using the reactor constructs so I don't know if it's good to bring in a `Scheduler` from the reactive world.

Comment: Well, like I said, you are already using it. 

If you really don't want that, you should have a class, lets say `SomeHttpClient`, which returns POJOs, not reactive constructs, then you can just make your db calls, also, no need to run the db call in another thread, just run that in your servlet contains worker thread. Of course, I don't have the full context of your setup, so thats just my opinions.

Comment: `WebClient has very limited worker threads` is not true in a non reactive application. A non reactive application will assign one thread per request, these are taken from the general threadpool.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf I don't think thats true, `WebClient` by default is using netty under the hood, and the client worker thread is very few depends on how many cores available on your machine, by default its 8x of the cores if I recall correctly.

Comment: @keinjom you are wrong again, a webflux application is using netty under the hood, a web application is a servlet application (as he is having) does not use netty.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf I am saying `WebClient`, you can use `WebClient` without using `webflux`, you can use it in a spring-mvc application, or any java applications. If that makes sense to you.

Also if you have read OP's post, he/she is not using webflux.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf here is what I copied from spring reference doc just now, hope that helps you to understand. "WebClient uses the same codecs as WebFlux server applications do, and shares a common base package, some common APIs, and infrastructure with the server functional web framework. The API exposes Reactor Flux and Mono types, also see Reactive Libraries. By default it uses it uses Reactor Netty as the HTTP client library ..." https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215287/discussion-between-kevinjom-and-thomas-andolf).